# setup.py opens pycharm, can't change file type

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, pycharm

quick question.
I'm trying to instal bs4 but when i run:
"setup.py install" it opens the .py file in my Pycharm.

Im unable to change the type (it will eventually use another type of program to open it). and I tried to remove the file association from PyCharm but have no positive results.

How can I stop PyCharm from opening the script from cmd when I run it ?

ps.: OS windows 7

Comment: What OS is this in? Windows?

Comment: Windows 7 as Operational system

Comment: I presume you're opening  a command window  in the folder where 'setup.py' is and doing it that way?

Comment: Solved.Had to uninstall PyCharm, install bs4 and re install pycharm.

Comment: future reference, my answer is a way to do it without uninstalling pycharm every time you want to install a new library. I'd recommend doing it 'my' way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand from your question, you're just clicking on the `setup.py` file and trying to install it that way which won't work. What you'll need to do is this:

1. Go into the folder where Bs4 is extracted to.
2. Where it has the content for the installation i.e setup.py
3. shift + right click in the folder, and click on `open command window here`
4. Final step! type `python setup.py install` in the command window.

That will then install the library!